# Proof of show transitivity between 3 variables with exponents

Tags: number-theory

If $a^5$ divides $b$ and $b^5$ divides $c,$ show that $a^{20}$ divides $c.$

Please help me prove this proposition.

Comment: Hint:  $b=a^5 n$ and $c=b^5 m.$  What are your thoughts beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write $b = a^5x_1$ and $c = b^5x_2$ for $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $c = b^5x_2 = (a^5x_1)^5 x_2 = a^{25} {x_1}^5 x_2$. We see that $a^{25}$ divides $c$, so in particular, $a^{20}$ divides $c$.

Answer (score 0):

as $a^5|b$ we have that $b=na^5$, equally from $b^5|c$ do we get that 
$$c=mb^5=m(na^5)^5=mn^5a^25=m(na)^5a^{20}$$
hence $a^{20}|c$